# PhantomJS: Slow from CI(Jenkins) server, but faster when executed from developers machine(Windows)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, phantomjs

I am having a really hard time figuring out as to why the selenium test cases are running slowly with phantomjs ghostdriver. When the developers run the test cases against the dev environment it runs faster(takes 1 hour to complete 5 test cases), but when ran from jenkins, it takes 4 hours.

I turned off the IPV6 on the dev machine, also tried switching to version 1.9.1, but still no improvement on the time taken.

### Jenkins Machine

phantomJS: 1.9.2
Jenkins Server: RHEL 5.6 64 bit
JDK: 1.7

### Developer Machine

OS: Windows 7 64 bit
JDK: 1.7
phantomJS: 1.9.2

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using driver.quit() or phantom.exit() after each test case as phantomJS process not get killed automatically. If no then it could be the reason of slowing down your test cases.

Comment: But the same test cases takes only short time when run on the developers box, but on linux it takes, lot of time.. I tried disabling IPV6, changing to version 1.9.1, but of no use.. Anyways will try what u said @Juli.

Answer (score 0):

If your tests do not quit the drivers, your jenkins box will have a lot of open browsers in memory after a while.

For instance, every test that starts, then asserts false somewhere and dies, leaves an unclosed driver.  These tend to build up after a while.

Depending on your testing framework.. there may be good solutions around it other than wrapping each test in their own try/catch blocks.

py.test has great fixture functionality.  You can have a phantomjsdriver() fixture that opend the browser for each test, then after the test is done (safely, or aborting from a False assertion)  it can finalize and close up the driver.

psudocode example: (py.test, python, selenium)

`@pytest.fixture
def phantomdriver(request):
    driver = webdriver.phantomJS()
    def fin():
        driver.close()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)`

In this situation, every test that uses this fixture, no mater how it exits, will end up calling the finilizer `fin()` to close it.